# GLSL shaders won't compile on VM Fusion - Windows 10/Visual Studio 2017

Tags: opengl, glsl, vmware-fusion

I have VMFusion installed on an external hard drive that I have connected to my 2014 Macbook Pro Retina Display. In this VM I have Windows 10 installed (not genuine) and Visual Studio 2017. I have my solution loaded (we use OpenGL), but when I compile and run, the console complains "error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, and 1.00 ES" when compiling any of our shaders.

In the VMFusion settings menu under Display, I see that the option for "Accelerate 3D Graphics" is already on. This option supposedly "Supports DirectX 10 and OpenGL 3.3". So I'm confused as to why I'm getting the error message about GLSL when I'm running my project. Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going on or how to solve this? I have the proper nuget packages installed and it seems like all the C++ code compiles just fine. It's purely the shaders. Is this a VMFusion problem or something not set up with my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

On your virtual machine, try to add next variables:

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE 3.3
MESA_GLES_VERSION_OVERRIDE 3.2
MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE 330
```

in both sections **"User variables"** and **"System variables"**
To open **"Advanced system settings"** follow **Control Panel -> System and Security -> System** click on **"Adanced system settings"**[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without further details (your GPU, the exact settings of the VM, etc).

However, I would suggest to check a few things:

1. Are **VMware tools** installed correctly on the guest OS?
2. What kind of **profile** are you requesting when you create your context (core or compatibility?) As far as I understand, VMware guests can get only OpenGL 3.3 **core** profile.

Then you can also have a look at VMware Fusion **documentation** about these issues [here](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2139606?sliceId=1&dialogID=124416581&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&stateId=0+0+124430259)